# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, websphere

I am trying to run a basic hibernate 5 program using maven. It gives error while creating the Configuration object. What am I missing ? Getting the following error:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.List); nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 132 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:283)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:994)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:865)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:544)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1068)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
    ... 134 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:786)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
    ... 153 more
```

I am using

- Spring 4
- Hibernate 5
- Maven
- RAD
- Websphere Application serve

**pom.xml**

Below is the pom dependency i added for Spring 4 and Hibernate 5.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     .
     .
     .
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**dao-context.xml:**

I am using jndi name which is configured in websphere application server admin console as datasource.

```
    <!-- turn on spring transaction annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Session Factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.pnc.wsp.bloa.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- dataSource configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/bloaDB" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

This sessionFactory is used in Dao class with autowiring like below

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: Probably if you share the POM and/or how did you implement your buildSessionFactory method as well.

Comment: @Walter - I have edited with pom & xml snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The SpringORM  version you are using is 4.2.4 .SO the compatible hibernate core versions are 5.0.5/4.3.11/3.6.10

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: I tried with all these version, still i have same issue. And i further thought it may be due to more than one version of hibernate, but i have only one version of hibernate core in my ear.